# SessionNotCreatedException: Chrome failed to start: exited normally. (session not created: DevToolsActivePort file doesn't exist)

Tags: python-3.x, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

First time using selenium for automated testing. But I don’t know that something abnormal occurs after opening Google Chrome.

```
def init_wbe_driver(chrome_data_dir):
    options = ChromeOptions()
    options.add_experimental_option('excludeSwitches', ['enable-automation'])
    options.add_experimental_option('useAutomationExtension', False)
    options.add_argument("--disable-blink-features")
    options.add_argument("--disable-blink-features=AutomationControlled")
    options.add_argument('--profile-directory=Default')
    options.add_argument(f"--user-data-dir={chrome_data_dir}")

    service = Service(ChromeDriverManager().install())

    driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=options,service=service)
    return driver


if __name__ == '__main__':
    driver = init_wbe_driver('C:/Users/Y/AppData/Local/Google/Chrome/User Data/')

    driver.get("https://izumi.finance/trade/swap")

    # driver.find_element()

    btton = driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR,".fweq4ws")

    btton.click()
    input("Press Enter to close the program...")
```

Exception information

```
selenium.common.exceptions.SessionNotCreatedException: Message: session not created: Chrome failed to start: exited normally.
  (session not created: DevToolsActivePort file doesn't exist)
  (The process started from chrome location C:\Program Files\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe is no longer running, so ChromeDriver is assuming that Chrome has crashed.)
Stacktrace:
    GetHandleVerifier [0x00C54CC3+225091]
    (No symbol) [0x00B84E11]
    (No symbol) [0x00A29A7A]
    (No symbol) [0x00A5198C]
    (No symbol) [0x00A4CF19]
    (No symbol) [0x00A87C71]
    (No symbol) [0x00A8790A]
    (No symbol) [0x00A7F2F6]
    (No symbol) [0x00A579B9]
    (No symbol) [0x00A5879D]
    sqlite3_dbdata_init [0x010C9A63+4064547]
    sqlite3_dbdata_init [0x010D106A+4094762]
    sqlite3_dbdata_init [0x010CB968+4072488]
    sqlite3_dbdata_init [0x00DCC9C9+930953]
    (No symbol) [0x00B907E4]
    (No symbol) [0x00B8AD08]
    (No symbol) [0x00B8AE31]
    (No symbol) [0x00B7CAA0]
    BaseThreadInitThunk [0x763A7BA9+25]
    RtlInitializeExceptionChain [0x774DBDAB+107]
    RtlClearBits [0x774DBD2F+191]
```

chrome version：123.0.6312.86

I try to execute,But Google programs carrying user data cannot be opened.

```
driver = init_wbe_driver('C:/Users/Y/AppData/Local/Google/Chrome/User Data/Default')
```

Comment: not sure you can use the default profile... you may want to make your own profile for use with the driver.  That may not be the issue, though... passing bad chromedriveroptions can cause crashes.  You have two entries for disable-blink-features, for instance.  Remove all your chromeOptions, and run.  If it works, add each option back in one at a time to see which one might be causing the issue.